# Наши сердца с народом Украины!

Tags: обсуждение

Происходящее в Украине — это трагедия, не поддающаяся описанию.

С первого дня существования проекта над сайтом работали люди из разных городов, в том числе Харькова, Запорожья и Симферополя. Многие участники нашего сообщества либо сами из Украины, либо у них есть родственники и друзья в Украине. Баз вашего участия, коллеги, нашего сообщества могло бы и не быть. Уверен, что выскажусь от лица каждого, кто когда–либо заглядывал к нам на Stack Overflow на русском: *Вы нам очень дороги! Нам всем больно видеть и верить в реальность происходящего.*

Наши сердца с вами!

Comment: Stack Overflow на русском — это в первую очередь люди. Мы с вами! Мы разные. Уникальные! Разбросанные по миру, социальным классам и поколениям. Но всех нас объединяет одно общее увлечение программированием и желание сделать мир лучше. Сайт был запущен более 10 лет назад. Со многими участниками, например, я, косвенно или напрямую, знаком лучше, чем с товарищами в оффлайне. Мне очень дороги эти люди.  Этот вопрос не о политике. Он о людях, ради которых мы приходим на этот сайт день за днем.

Comment: Так и я тоже человек, или я хуже? Здесь не место для выражения политического мнения, каким бы оно ни было. Удаление комментариев - это ваш выход. Очень и очень приятно

Comment: @Dmitry это позиция команды проекта, а не личного политического мнения. Они имеют полное право ее высказать. Если вы с ней не согласны - можете в знак протеста перестать пользоваться SO

Comment: @PashaPash, можно, но это такой же бесполезный шаг как и любой другой протест, если ты кроме протеста ничего больше сделать не сможешь.

Comment: @PashaPash я не протестую и не выражаю политических предпочтений. Я, лишь, указываю на то, что мета _это сайт, где участники обсуждают технические и организационные аспекты работы сайта Stack Overflow на русском._ Это есть в [Справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Для выражения позиция команды сайта должны быть другие ресурсы, которые не мешают и не противоречат правилам ресурса. Это весь мой посыл. Все остальное я оставлю при себе, поскольку это не несет пользы для ресурса

Comment: @Dmitry из той же справки «... общения компании Stack Exchange с сообществом - ..., обсуждение правил поведения **и других вопросов, влияющих на жизнь сообщества.** ...». Формально сообщение подходит для Меты. Тем более уже было много прецедентов когда CM использовал вопросы на Мете для поздравлений, видеочатов и информационных сообщений.

Comment: @defaultlocale _Не задавайте вопросов, которые не имеют отношения к Stack Overflow на русском или, как минимум, к сети Stack Exchange. Это не площадка для обсуждения всевозможных тематик, а место для улучшения жизни нашего сообщества и сайта в целом._ Мнение: политика не имеет отношения к SO. Данный вопрос не улучшает жизнь нашего сообщества и сайта в целом, но может внести негатив и раздоры, все из-за той же _уникальности людей._  Формально, тогда абсолютно любой вопрос подходит для Меты. Очень сильно надеюсь, что моя позиция не будет расценена, как сочувствие к одной из стороне конфликта.

Comment: @KoVadim это - выбор. Ваш и людей, которые обозначают свою принадлежность. Этот выбор надо уважать, да, что выбор, просто надо уважать людей и точка.

Comment: @Dmitry ну вот и уважайте выбор команды SO опубликовать пост о своем отношении к происходящему на сайте. Использование голосов за закрытие вразрез с правилами - это нарушение. Использование их для продвижения своей политической позиции - тем более.

Comment: @Dmitry мне нравится как вы взяли "команду" в кавычки. ок, сорри, мог неправильно понять контекст.

Comment: @PashaPash поскольку я не знаком с ними, для меня это эфемерно и непонятно. Если это касается модераторов то уверен, что не все модераторы готовы поддерживать политически направленные посты. Все равно за кого, за Украину, за Россию, за Америку и проч.

Comment: @timob256 ваши комментарии и ответы, как и сам пост имеет четкую направленность на политику. Вы можете высказываться, но не здесь. Данная площадка не для этого. Я поддержу удаление комментариев и ответов, которые разжигают и не несут объективности с любой стороны. И еще раз, вы - человек и имеете право. Но правила ресурса, надеюсь, для всех и нет никого лучше или хуже

Comment: @Dmitry этот пост не политически направлен. он не призывает воевать (или не воевать), не говорит что Россия / Украина хорошие или плохие, и не призывает никого убивать. Это пост поддержки и сочуствия тем, участникам, кто вынужденно, не по своей воле, оказался сейчас в районе боевых действий (попавших под хлопки в зоне спецоперации, если вам так удобнее).

Comment: ❤ Спасибо вам!)

Comment: You cannot vote to close after retracting your vote...но я не голосовал за закрытие этого вопроса вообще, хотел просто предлагаемые причины закрытия посмотреть.

Comment: @aepot - не воспроизводится. Если что, причины все четыре: "Скорее всего, данный вопрос не относится ни к обсуждению работы сайта Stack Overflow "

Comment: @aepot Сообщение закрыто по причине «Невозможно дать объективный ответ» участниками Dmitry, Alexander Igorevich, MSDN.WhiteKnight, TimurVI, aepot

Comment: @yolosora я в списке последний, поэтому время закрытия должно совпадать с моим голосом, но в 6:32 я обычно сплю. Либо я во сне что-то закрыл (5G прививка работает!), либо меня похитили инопланетяне, и это был не я. Ну ок, меня устраивает любой из вариантов.

Comment: @aepot почему вашего ответа больше не существует?

Comment: @return я удалил, считаю, что он здесь больше не нужен. Несмотря на то что я был краток, в комментах под ответом пошла политота, поспорили, и хватит.

Comment: а тем временем на главной висит вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1387937/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-%d1%81-upwork и ни один модератор не тронет его. а в одной стране, которую тут нельзя называть, за такое могут и 15 лет дать. Но лучше пусть он повисит, забанят и будет норм

Comment: @KoVadim ну я как бы не вижу в том посте состава преступления, карточки действительно больше не обслуживаются для международных платежей. Насчет пэйпала хз, я им не пользовался никогда. Вопрос вряд-ли будет отвечен, потому что никто просто технически здесь пока не знает ответа, рано еще, каждый день всё меняется. Вы себя зря не накручивайте, надо иногда выдыхать, иначе с ума можно сойти.

Comment: не в пейпале дело. действительно. Но если "состава приступления" не видите, то мне нечего добавить.

Comment: @KoVadim вы про 15 лет за фейки о действиях военных?

Comment: я думаю, что ответ на мой вопрос очевиден.

Comment: @KoVadim совершенно нет. Там же ни слова про них. А только про блокировку карт.

Comment: @PashaPash ¿А что это пост о *своем* отношении - инфа 100? Мне и пост, и (потертые) ответы скорее напоминают бородатый анекдот: *Идет партсобрание. Парторг: – Рабинович, а вы почему не выступаете? У вас что, нет своих мыслей? – Почему же? Есть! – Так почему же вы молчите? – А я с ними не согласен.*

Comment: @user7860670 ну ок, согласен, есть те, кому не больно смотреть на происходящее, и кого это наоборот, радует. Даже в it встречаются бездушные идиоты, которые радуются войне, разрушениями и смертям, что поделать.

Comment: @PashaPash возможно они не идиоты, им просто страшно. Они не знают что делать и как реагировать.

Comment: Я сегодня на сайте впервые с того дня, как утром проснулся от крика жены "Война!". Можете удалить мой комментарий, но за эти три недели я насмотрелся всего, мне уже не страшно потерять даже членство здесь — после того, как мои сотрудники на работе потеряли дома, неделями голодали в подвалах, собирая воду из водостоков, а некоторые знакомые знакомых (начинается, как при ковиде...) уже и вовсе погибли. Я в Киеве, я никуда не уехал. Об этой @#%@$ой войне скажу только одно — в ней проиграно самое главное: увы, я вижу зашкаливающую ненависть к РФ даже ранее очень пророссийски настроенных людей...

Comment: о, тут комментарии со словом война удаляют. Но я рад, что я буду не один бороться

Comment: @Harry, держитесь, и пребудет с вами удача